# Search a Pandas Dataframe having hierarchical indexing by a single column

Tags: pandas, search, indexing, hierarchical

I'm working with this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'one',  105], ['A', 'two',  101], ['A', 'three',  103],
                      ['B','one',  101], ['B','two',  1102], ['B','three',  1050]],
                   columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
df = df.set_index(['c1', 'c2'])
df
```

Which returns

```
               c3
c1    c2    
A     one     105
      two     101
      three   103
B     one     101
      two     1102
      three   1050
```

... and I'd like to sort by column c3, preserving rows and c1 sort, to get this:

```
              c3
c1    c2    
A     one     105
      three   103
      two     101
B     two     1102
      three   1050
      one     101
```

I've not been able to come up with a method that doesn't jumble the c1 sort. In particular, a final `df.sort_index()` returns `KeyError: 'c1'`

Comment: I still didn't get your logic. Are you trying to sort by c1 in ascending order and c3 descending? I don't see the logic or sorting in c2 and c3. If you sort by c2, then it should be one three two, if by c3, then 1102 should be at the top or bottom.

Comment: 1102 should be at the top since it is greater than 1050  agreed with @TYZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can do:

```
out = (df.sort_values(['c3','c1'],ascending=False)
      .reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),level=0))
```

---

```
            c3
c1 c2         
A  one     105
   three   103
   two     101
B  two    1102
   three  1050
   one     101
```

Comment: Yes, you saw through my typo, and that does it, thanks!

Comment: @anky_91 Is groupby a better option or reindex?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just use:

```
df.sort_values(['c1','c3'], ascending=False).groupby(['c1','c3']).agg(lambda x: x)
```

Output:

```
            c3
c1 c2         
B  two    1102
   three  1050
   one     101
A  one     105
   three   103
   two     101
```

Comment: thank you @anky_91, I was not sure about it, that's why I asked

Comment: @anky_91 sure, will let you know